# Summing an array of integers in Javascript using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm new to recursion and want to sum an array of integers.

```
sumOfInts([1,2,3,4]) //expected output: 10
```

My try:

```js
function sumOfInts(array) {
  let counter = 0;
  let result = 0;
  if (counter === array.length - 2) {
    return result + array[array.length - 1]
  } else {
    result += array[counter];
    counter++;
  }
}
```

I tried a few things for the function to invoke itself in the else-statement, but failed so far.

Right now, the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I don't see any recursion. If you want to sum all values of array you can use something like: `[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sliced the array until it becomes empty, and increased sum value with the first element of it. Since you are learning recursive, I thought this solution would help you to understand recursion better. However, considering good practices and performance, you should prefer [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over this.

```
function sumOfInts(array, sum = 0) {
    if (array.length === 0) return sum;
    return sumOfInts(array.slice(1), sum + array[0]);
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but note the potential flaw caused by the default value: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5, 7]].map(sumOfInts) //=> [10, 13, 19]`, when it should be `[10, 12, 17]`.  This is because on the second call, sum is initialized with `map's` index argument of `1`, and on the third with `2`.  While you can always write `[...].map(ns => sumOfInts(ns))`, this sort of thing has bitten me more than once.

Comment: You made a very good point here, I had not considered such a case. What kind of change would you recommend to make the function more reliable?

Comment: I know of nothing better than wrapping.  If we rename that internal implementation (and it's recursive call) to `_sumOfInts`, removing the default value,  then we can publicly expose only `const sumOfInts = (array) => _sumOfInts (array, 0)`.  It's not beautiful, but I haven't found a better alternative.

Comment: I completely agree with you on wrapping. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is an exercise, you don't need recursion for this. IMHO `Array#reduce` is better suited for this task:

```js
const sum = xs => xs.reduce((tot, x) => tot + x, 0);
sum([1,2,3,4]);
//=> 10
```

With recursion, you should leverage parameter destructuring and default value:

```js
const sum = ([x = 0, ...xs]) => xs.length === 0 ? x : x + sum(xs);
sum([1,2,3,4]);
//=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is a version with the classic functional programming ingredients head and tail:

```
const head = ([h]) => h;                                      
const tail = ([, ...t]) => t;                                   
const sumOfInts = (array) =>  array.length == 0 ? 0 : head(array) +                                                          
                                                      sumOfInts(tail(array))                                                                         


sumOfInts([1,2,3,4])
// => 10
```

Comment: If you're going to define `head` and `tail`, then why not just `const sumOfInts = (array) =>  array.length == 0 ? 0 : head(array) + sumOfInts(tail(array))`?  That's much cleaner and more in line with thinking of an array as something with a head and a tail.  Either version has potential recursion-depth problems in JS.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for the great help. Amazing what is possible with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

```
function sumOfInts(arr) {
  if (arr.length > 0){
    //Check if length is greater than 0 .
    //If yes then get all the element but not the last
    //And recursively pass the spliced array to the sumOfInts.
    return sumOfInts(arr.splice(0,arr.length - 1)) + arr[0]; 
  }
  return 0;
}
let sum = sumOfInts([1,2,3,4,5]) ;
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: The array given as parameter is changed here. You should use `slice` instead of `splice` to avoid side-effects.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. We could have used a copy of the array but as you said slice would be the better option.